# i have an exported file that comes out with spaces, and i want to change that file to have hyphens

Tags: python

My current code is:

```
import os

path  = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir("C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/")

filename = ('Leap Price Guide Export.xlsx')

for filename in filenames:
      os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(' ', '-')))

for filename in filenames:
     os.rename(filename, filename.replace(" ", "-"))
```

but i get error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\larso\\Desktop\\ClearEstimatesEstimate\\AutomateExcelfileintoaspecficExcelfileformat\\AutomateExcelfileintoaspecficExcelfileformat' -> 'C:\\Users\\larso\\Desktop\\ClearEstimatesEstimate\\AutomateExcelfileintoaspecficExcelfileformat\\AutomateExcelfileintoaspecficExcelfileformat'
```

any thoughts how to automate that

Comment: Remove your first for statement where you are joining the CWD with your file names.

Comment: i removed the CWD but still got the same result

Comment: You rename files in the first loop, thus files with spaces no longer exist in the file system after the first loop. In second loop, you still expect old filenames (those in filenames) to be present, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:

Has your path variable

```
path  = os.getcwd()
```

the same path as your filenames path

```
filenames = os.listdir("C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/")
```

Because you combine the path from the *path* variable with the *filename* from an filenames variable.

```
os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Please print both path values and compare them for differences. Or better use your *path* variable in your *filenames* variable:

```
filenames = os.listdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` is going to give you the path from which you're running the script.

`os.listdir(path)` is going to give you the list of filenames in the directory at path.

So the absolute path of the file in your working directory will be:

```py
os.getcwd() + '/' + filename
```

Try this, with your script in the same directory as your files you want to rename.

```py
import os

path  = os.getcwd()

filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
      current_filename = path + '/' + filename
      os.rename(current_filename, current_filename.replace('_', ' '))
```

Comment: So the path wasn't correct so i tried
path =('C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/Leap Price Guide Export.xlsx')
#filename ('Leap Price Guide Export.xlsx')
for filename in filenames:
      current_filename = path + '/' + filename
      os.rename(current_filename, current_filename.replace(' ', '_'))

got error 

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/Leap Price Guide Export.xlsx/.ipynb checkpoints' -> 'C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/Leap_Price_Guide_Export.xlsx/.ipynb_checkpoints

Comment: print(path)

shows as 

C:/Users/Larso/Desktop/ClearEstimatesEstimate/Leap Price Guide Export.xlsx

which looks to be the correct navigation to it

Comment: You won't have to specify the path (and maybe get it wrong) if you put this script in the same folder as the files you want to rename. Does that not work for you?